# Can't delete or update data data from jTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

i have a mydata.txt file with this in it:

```
Сухачёв Денис Владимирович, ИИТиУТС, 1, 11
Жмышенко Валерий Альбертович, ИЯЭиП, 3, 31
Ларин Дмитрий Александрович, ИРИБ, 2, 14
```

I need to open this text file and put information in a JTable so that I can then add, remove or update information. with the ability to sort and save the file

The JTable should have the following columns:
 `Name, University, Quarter, Number of days.`
I was told that I need to read the text line by line, put it in an Arraylist and then split the lines for each "," <is in the JTable

I use my class to read or write to a file :

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class NIO {


    public static List<String> inpLines(String paths) throws IOException { //read file

        Charset charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
        // Задаем кодировку файла
        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>(); // Создаем колекцию Строк

        Path path = Paths.get(paths); // получаем путь к файлу

        try {

            lines = Files.readAllLines(path, charset); // читаем строки

        } catch (IOException e) {

            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return lines;
    }
    
    public static List<Result> StringsToResults(List<String> lines) { //Split lines


        List<Result> results = new ArrayList<Result>();

        for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {

            String[] words = lines.get(i).split(",");

            Result r = new Result();
            r.setTeacherId(words[0].trim());
            r.setCodeUniversity(words[1].trim());

            try {
                r.setNumQuarter(Integer.parseInt(words[2].trim()));
                r.setAmountDays(Integer.parseInt(words[3].trim()));

            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                return null;
            }

            results.add(r);

        }
        return results;
    }

    public static boolean outpLines (String fileName, List <String> lines )
            throws IOException { //writing to file

        PrintWriter out = null;
        if ((lines==null)|| lines.isEmpty()) return false;
        try {

            out=new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(fileName));
            int n=lines.size();
            for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
                out.println(lines.get(i).trim());
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            return false;}
        finally {
            if (out != null) out.close();
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static List <String> ResultsToString (List <Result> results) { //Formatting for writing to a file
        if (results==null || results.isEmpty ()) return null;

        List <String> lines = new ArrayList <String> ();

        for (Result res: results)
            lines.add(String.format("%10s, %10s, %5d, %5d", res.getTeacherId(),
                    res.getCodeUniversity(), res.getNumQuarter(),res.getAmountDays()));
        return lines;
    }

}
```

For displaying tabular data, I have implemented ResultTableModel

```
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import java.util.List;

    public class ResultTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
        private static final int COLUMN_ID = 0;
        private static final int COLUMN_CODE = 1;
        private static final int COLUMN_NUM = 2;
        private static final int COLUMN_AMOUNT = 3;

        private String[] columnNames = {"Номер Преподавателя", "Шифр Вуза", "Номер Квартала", "Количество Дней"};

        List<Result> results; 
        

        public ResultTableModel(List<Result> results) {
            this.results = results;

        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return columnNames.length;
        } // +

        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int columnIndex) {
            return columnNames[columnIndex];
        } // +

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return results.size();
        } // +

        public Class getColumnClass( int columnIndex) {

            if (results.isEmpty()) {
                return Object.class;
            }
            return getValueAt(0, columnIndex).getClass();
        }

        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            Result result = getResult(rowIndex); // мб изменить Result result = get(row);
            Object returnValue = null;

            switch (columnIndex) {
                case COLUMN_ID:
                    returnValue = result.getTeacherId();
                    break;
                case COLUMN_CODE:
                    returnValue = result.getCodeUniversity();
                    break;
                case COLUMN_NUM:
                    returnValue = result.getNumQuarter();
                    break;
                case COLUMN_AMOUNT:
                    returnValue = result.getAmountDays();
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid column index");
            }

            return returnValue;
        }

        @Override
        public void setValueAt(Object value, int rowIndex, int columnIndex)
        {
            Result result = getResult(rowIndex);

            switch (columnIndex) {
                case COLUMN_ID:
                     result.setTeacherId((String) value);
                    break;
                case COLUMN_CODE:
                     result.setCodeUniversity((String) value);
                    break;
                case COLUMN_NUM:
                     result.setNumQuarter((Integer) value);
                    break;
                case COLUMN_AMOUNT:
                     result.setAmountDays((Integer) value);
                    break;

            }
            fireTableCellUpdated(rowIndex, columnIndex);
        }


        public Result getResult(int rowIndex)
        {
            return results.get(rowIndex);
        }

    }
```

And using an object Result

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Result {
    private String teacherId; // Айди Преподователя
    private String codeUniversity; // Шифр Вуза
    private int numQuarter; // Номер Квартала
    private int amountDays; // Количество Дней



    public Result() {

        teacherId = "";
        codeUniversity = "";
        numQuarter = 0;
        amountDays = 0;


    }

    public Result(String teacherId, String codeUniversity, int numQuarter, int amountDays){

        this.teacherId = teacherId;
        this.codeUniversity = codeUniversity;
        this.numQuarter = numQuarter;
        this.amountDays = amountDays;

    }


    public String getTeacherId() { return teacherId; }
    public String getCodeUniversity() { return codeUniversity; }
    public int getNumQuarter() { return numQuarter; }
    public int getAmountDays() { return amountDays; }


    public void setTeacherId(String teacherId) { this.teacherId = teacherId; }
    public void setCodeUniversity(String codeUniversity) { this.codeUniversity = codeUniversity; }
    public void setNumQuarter(int numQuarter) { this.numQuarter = numQuarter; }
    public void setAmountDays(int amountDays) { this.amountDays = amountDays; }



}
```

I use the global class to access the functions, although I was as stupid as possible here due to lack of knowledge

```
import java.util.*;
public class Global {

    public static ResultGroup table;

    public static List <Result> results;

    static ResultTableModel tableModel;

    public static void updateJTable(List <Result> res){

        results.clear();
        results.addAll(res);
        tableModel.fireTableDataChanged();
    }
}
```

And I use the class to work with tabular data

```
import java.util.*;

public class ResultGroup {

    public  List <Result> results;
    
    public ResultGroup() {
        results = new ArrayList <Result>();
    }

    public ResultGroup(List list){
       results = new ArrayList <Result>(list);

    }

    public List <Result> getResults(){
        return results;
    }


    public boolean addResult(Result res){

        if (getResult(res)!=null)
            return false;
        if (results.add(res)) return true;
        else return false;
    }


    public boolean delResult(Result res){
        if (getResult(res)!=null)
            return false;
        if (results.remove(res)) return true;
        else return false;
    }
    public boolean updateResult(Result res){
       
        Result r = getResult(res);
        if (r!=null) {r.setAmountDays(res.getAmountDays()); return true;}
        return false;
    }

    public Result getResult (Result res){
        for (Result r : results)

            if (r.equals(res)) return r;
        return null;
    }           
}
```

And I use it all in the application

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException;



public class MDIApplication extends javax.swing.JFrame implements ActionListener{

    String directoryName ="C:/";
    String fileName="";
    File curFile;
    java.util.List <String> LINES;

    private javax.swing.JLabel currentOpenFile;
    private javax.swing.JTextField filterCode;
    private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel numUniversity;
    private javax.swing.JLabel sMessages;
    JTextField idTeacherTextField;
    JTextField codeUTextField;
    JTextField numQTextField;
    JTextField amountDTextField;

    public   MDIApplication() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {


        Global.table = new ResultGroup();
        Global.results = new ArrayList<>();
        Global.tableModel = new ResultTableModel(Global.results);
        TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter;
        jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable(Global.tableModel);

        filterCode = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        currentOpenFile = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        JLabel headerTable = new JLabel();
        JScrollPane jScrollPane1 = new JScrollPane();

        JLabel editTable = new JLabel();
        JLabel idTeacherLabel = new JLabel();
        JLabel codeULabel = new JLabel();
        JLabel numQLabel = new JLabel();
        JLabel amountDLabel = new JLabel();
        idTeacherTextField = new JTextField();
        codeUTextField = new JTextField();
        numQTextField = new JTextField();
        amountDTextField = new JTextField();
        JButton addButton = new JButton();
        JButton updateButton = new JButton();
        JButton delButton = new JButton();
        JButton clearButton = new JButton();
        sMessages = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        JLabel numViewULabel = new JLabel();
        numUniversity = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        JButton viewButton = new JButton();
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu();
        JMenuItem openMenuItem = new JMenuItem();
        JMenuItem saveMenuItem = new JMenuItem();
        JMenuItem saveAsMenuItem = new JMenuItem();
        JMenuItem exitMenuItem = new JMenuItem();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);







        TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel> trs = new TableRowSorter(jTable1.getModel());
        jTable1.setRowSorter(trs);
        List<RowSorter.SortKey> sortKeys = new ArrayList<>();
        sortKeys.add(new RowSorter.SortKey(3, SortOrder.ASCENDING));
        sortKeys.add(new RowSorter.SortKey(1, SortOrder.DESCENDING));
        trs.setSortKeys(sortKeys);
        trs.sort();
        jTable1.setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
        jTable1.setFocusable(false);
        jTable1.setGridColor(new java.awt.Color(236, 236, 236));
        jTable1.setSelectionBackground(new java.awt.Color(213, 227, 239));
        jTable1.setSelectionMode(javax.swing.ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        jTable1.setShowGrid(true);

        jTable1.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {

                int setSelectedRow = jTable1.rowAtPoint(evt.getPoint());
                idTeacherTextField.setText(Global.tableModel.getValueAt(trs.convertRowIndexToModel(setSelectedRow),  0).toString());
                codeUTextField.setText(Global.tableModel.getValueAt(trs.convertRowIndexToModel(setSelectedRow), 1).toString());
                numQTextField.setText(Global.tableModel.getValueAt(trs.convertRowIndexToModel(setSelectedRow), 2).toString());
                amountDTextField.setText(Global.tableModel.getValueAt(trs.convertRowIndexToModel(setSelectedRow), 3).toString());
            }
        });
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);



        addButton.setText("Добавить");
        addButton.addActionListener(this::addButtonActionPerformed);

        updateButton.setText("Обновить");
        updateButton.addActionListener(this::updateButtonActionPerformed);

        delButton.setText("Удалить");
        delButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
               
                int n,n2;
                String str1, str2, str3 ,str4;
                str1=idTeacherTextField.getText(); str2=codeUTextField.getText();  str3=numQTextField.getText(); str4=amountDTextField.getText();
                if (str1.equals("")||str2.equals("")||str3.equals("")||str4.equals("")){
                    sMessages.setText("Задайте значения полей");
                    return;}
                n=Integer.parseInt(str3);
                n2=Integer.parseInt(str4);

                sMessages.setText(
                        "   Запрос на удаление записи по ключу");
                Global.table.delResult(new Result(str1,str2,n,n2));
                Global.updateJTable(Global.table.getResults());
                idTeacherTextField.setText(""); codeUTextField.setText(""); numQTextField.setText(""); amountDTextField.setText("");

            }
        });

        clearButton.setText("Очистить");
        clearButton.addActionListener(this::clearButtonActionPerformed);

        /*
        using Location Manager to display GROUPLAYOUT
         */
    }


    public void OpenFile(){
        JFileChooser chooser= new JFileChooser(directoryName);
        FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
                "Текстовые Документы", "txt");
        chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
        chooser.setDialogTitle("Открыть...");
        int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(this);
        if (returnVal== JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
            curFile=chooser.getSelectedFile();
            fileName=curFile.getAbsolutePath();
            int n =fileName.lastIndexOf('\\');
            directoryName=fileName.substring(0,n+1);
            try{
                LINES = NIO.inpLines(fileName);
                if (LINES!=null) sMessages.setText("Успешное открытие файла!");
                else sMessages.setText("Ошибка открытия файла!");
            }catch (Exception e) {sMessages.setText("Ошибка открытия файла!");}
            java.util.List <Result> res = NIO.StringsToResults(LINES);
            Global.table.getResults().clear();
            assert res != null;
            for (Result r: res) Global.table.addResult(r);
            Global.updateJTable(Global.table.getResults());
            
        }
    }
    
    private void SaveDialog(){
        JFileChooser chooser= new JFileChooser(directoryName);
        FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
                "Текстовые Документы", "txt");
        chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
        chooser.setDialogTitle("Сохранить...");
        int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(this);
        if (returnVal== JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
            curFile=chooser.getSelectedFile();
            fileName=curFile.getAbsolutePath();
            int n = fileName.lastIndexOf('\\');
            directoryName=fileName.substring(0,n+1);
        }
    }
    
    public void SaveFile(boolean fs){
        String old_file_name=fileName;
        sMessages.setText("   Сохранение файла");
        if (fs) SaveDialog();
        else  if (fileName.equals("")) SaveDialog();

        if  (curFile==null){sMessages.setText(
                "   Файл для сохранения не выбран"); return;}
        if ((!curFile.exists())|| fileName.equals(old_file_name)){
            LINES = NIO.ResultsToString(Global.table.getResults());
            try{
                boolean f=NIO.outpLines(fileName, LINES);
                if (f)  {sMessages.setText("    Данные успешно сохранены"); currentOpenFile.setText(fileName);}
                else   sMessages.setText("    Ошибка сохранения данных");}
            catch (Exception e) { sMessages.setText("    Ошибка сохранения данных");}

        }

    }

    

    private void addButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

        int n,n2;
        String str1, str2, str3 ,str4;
        str1=idTeacherTextField.getText(); str2=codeUTextField.getText();  str3=numQTextField.getText(); str4=amountDTextField.getText();
        if (str1.equals("")||str2.equals("")||str3.equals("")||str4.equals("")){
            sMessages.setText("Задайте значения полей");
            return;}
        try{//Контролируем исключения при преобразовании из String в число
            n=Integer.parseInt(str3);
        }//try
        catch (NumberFormatException  e){// обработчик исключения для try
            sMessages.setText("   Задайте правильно число голов");
            return;}
        try{//Контролируем исключения при преобразовании из String в число
            n2=Integer.parseInt(str4);
        }//try
        catch (NumberFormatException  e){// обработчик исключения для try
            sMessages.setText("   Задайте правильно число голов");
            return;}
        sMessages.setText(
                "   Запрос на добавление записи в таблицу");
        if (!Global.table.addResult(new Result(str1,str2,n,n2)))
            sMessages.setText(
                    "   Запись не добавлена, возможно нарушена уникальность ключа");
        Global.updateJTable(Global.table.getResults());
        idTeacherTextField.setText(""); codeUTextField.setText(""); numQTextField.setText(""); amountDTextField.setText("");
    }

    private void updateButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        int n,n2;
        String str1, str2, str3 ,str4;
        str1=idTeacherTextField.getText(); str2=codeUTextField.getText();  str3=numQTextField.getText(); str4=amountDTextField.getText();
        if (str1.equals("")||str2.equals("")||str3.equals("")||str4.equals("")){
            sMessages.setText("Задайте значения полей");
            return;}
        try{//Контролируем исключения при преобразовании из String в число
            n=Integer.parseInt(str3);
        }//try
        catch (NumberFormatException  e){// обработчик исключения для try
            sMessages.setText("   Задайте правильно число голов");
            return;}
        try{//Контролируем исключения при преобразовании из String в число
            n2=Integer.parseInt(str4);
        }//try
        catch (NumberFormatException  e){// обработчик исключения для try
            sMessages.setText("   Задайте правильно число голов");
            return;}
        sMessages.setText(
                "   Запрос на обновление записи в таблице");
        if (!Global.table.updateResult(new Result(str1,str2,n,n2)))
            sMessages.setText(
                    "   Запись не обновлена, возможно записи с таким ключом нет");
        Global.updateJTable(Global.table.getResults());
        idTeacherTextField.setText(""); codeUTextField.setText(""); numQTextField.setText(""); amountDTextField.setText("");
    }

    private void clearButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

        idTeacherTextField.setText(""); codeUTextField.setText(""); numQTextField.setText(""); amountDTextField.setText("");
    }




    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException | IllegalAccessException | InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MDIApplication.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }


        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> new MDIApplication().setVisible(true));
    }


}
```

I tried to shorten the code, but still please forgive me

Comment: I don't understand the structure of your code. You have multiple classes that extend JFrame (I don't know why). You appear to be using a static variable to access all your variable across classes. Again, this is extremely confusing. All updated to the table need to be done via the TableModel. Your TableModel implementation doesn't look complete. I don't see your `setValueAt(...)` method, so how can you update the data? I don't see your "deleteRow(...)" method, so how can you delete a row of data?

Comment: Maybe the [RowTableModel](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/21/row-table-model/) example will give you a better example of implementing a TableModel. You also should not be using a MouseListener to select a row. You should be using a ListSelectionListener. This will allow the user to use either a mouse or the keyboard to select a row.

Comment: @camickr
I am very grateful to you for your help, but I am completely confused. Could you see my code that I will send you?

Comment: *"Could you see my code that I will send you?"* Prepare a [mre] and [edit] the question to add it.

Comment: @andrew-thompson I tried

Comment: @ Andrew Thompson     If that I posted for convenience in github [link]https://github.com/Danglarm/JTableExp

Comment: *"for convenience"* Whose? An MRE is convenient for us, the people who might try to help. That code dump seen above **is not** an MRE that other people can easily compile and test. Please read the original document carefully, and this one on the [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/) - to try & understand the form of code likely to get help.

Comment: *I am completely confused* - because you don't understand how to use a TableModel. So start simple. Create a JFrame with a JTable that uses the DefaultTableModel with a couple of rows of hard coded data. Then you create "Add" and "Remove" buttons. These buttons will add a row of data or remove a row of data from the DefaultTableModel. All the logic will be fully contained in a single class. If you have problems then you have an [mre] you can post.

Comment: Once you understand the relationship between the JTable and the TableModel, then you simply replace the DefaultTableModel with your ResutTableModel. When you are ready to do this. Get rid of ResultGroup!!! As I already stated ALL updates are done via the ResultSetTableModel. I showed you how to implement add(...) and remove(..) method directly in the model.

Comment: You said you can't  delete or update data from the table. Did you set the cells/rows as editable? In the table model class there is a method for it: "public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex)".